# Suppress auto-closing window in Watir

Tags: ruby, google-chrome, watir

I am using Watir with Chromedriver to automate form submission on some website.  I have to login and submit multiple forms.  The problem is, when I click the submit button the page the page automatically closes, so when I goto('next_url') I get this error:

/Users/jackz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.27.2/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:52:in `assert_ok': 'auto_id' does not refer to an open tab (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError)

The Watir instance is still there, but the window is closed.  I could create a new instance every time, but then I would have to login again every time and this would take longer.

So how can I either:

Open a new window in the same Watir instance

or

Suppress the window from closing after I submit

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
@b = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
@b.goto(URL)
@b.buttons.first.click

#this is when the window closes
@b.goto(NEW_URL)
#then I get an error
```

Thanks

Comment: Does the window close automatically when you do the same thing manually?

Comment: Yes, successfully submitting anything on the page manually or through Watir closes it.

Comment: In that case you should as the developers what you should so the window does not close.

Comment: Ah yea asking the developers is probably not an option, I am using a web application developed by a giant bank...I figured out a workaround to the problem though.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out an answer to my own question.  I can open a new window in Watir using javascript:

```
b = Watir::Browser.new
b.execute_script("window.open()")
b.windows.last.use
```

This opens a window where I can fill out the form, then when the window automatically closes I still have the original window to work with.  Probably not the best solution, but it works for now.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your existing code if your using `chrome`. else, modify accordingly as per your browser.

This will keep the window open, and the current `watir` session active.

```
caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome("chromeOptions" => {'detach' => false})
browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
```

Answer (score 1):

What Mrityunjeyan suggested above was in a right direction, but you need to change a few things to make it work.

```
caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome("chromeOptions" => {'detach' => true })
b = Watir::Browser.new('chrome', desired_capabilities: caps)
```

Check the documentation here.
https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities